# Regular expression unix switch num

Tags: regex

I have the following text:

```
 (took 1.22 seconds)
```

need to replace the time to TIME using regex.
I want the string to be:

```
 (took TIME seconds)
```

how can I do it?

I am using a script in Unix similar to the following:

```
's/user detected .*$/user detected USER/g'
```

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: script in unix: similar to the following

Comment: 's/user detected .*$/user detected USER/g'

Comment: So, you need something like [`sed 's/^took [0-9].*/took TIME seconds/'`](https://ideone.com/39QdyI)? Or [`sed -E 's/[0-9]*\.?[0-9]{2}/TIME/g'`](https://ideone.com/8bJ6cz)?

Answer (score 0):

You may use any of the `sed` solutions below:

```
s='took 1.22 seconds'
echo $s | sed  's/ [0-9]*\.\?[0-9]\{2\} / TIME /g'
echo $s | sed -E 's/[0-9]*\.?[0-9]{2}/TIME/g'
echo $s | sed -E 's/\b[0-9]*\.?[0-9]{2}\b/TIME/g'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/8bJ6cz)

The patterns mean:

- `[0-9]*` - zero or more digits
- `\.?` - 1 or 0 dots
- `[0-9]{2}` - 2 digits
- `\b` - word boundary.